# Vectorizing Density Evaluation

Tags: matlab

I would like to vectorize the following loop:

```
k=4
n=5
w=randn(n,1)
theta = randn(n,k)
for i=1:size(theta,1)
    s = w(i)*mvnpdf(theta(i,:)',zeros(k,1),eye(k));
end
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mvnpdf` is already vectorized for each row of the first parameter. If you had
the 1st parameter's rows of the N-by-D matrix correspond to observations or points, and columns correspond to variables or coordinates then you can use the vectorization as follows (assuming `w` is a column vector).

```
news = w .* mvnpdf( theta', zeros(n,k), eye(k) );
```

**However**, your dimensions of `theta` are not structured like that so you need to use `cellfun` to compute it instead of using the loop. You will need my very useful custom [cols2cell.m function](http://pastebin.com/XitBAS6j).

```
k=4
n=5
w=randn(n,1)
theta = randn(n,k)
newtheta = theta';
for i=1:size(theta,1)
    s(i) = w(i) * mvnpdf(theta(i,:)',zeros(k,1),eye(k));
end

news = w .* cellfun( @(x) mvnpdf( x, zeros(k,1), eye(k) ), cols2cell( newtheta ) )';
```

Your function can be defined to take in the cell column vector. `x` is the column vector fed into the first parameter of `mvnpdf`.

```
@(x) mvnpdf( x, zeros(k,1), eye(k) )
```

The result of the `cellfun` call is a row vector that needs to be transposed. You can do an element wise multiplication with `w` afterwards. The results are verified to be the same.

```
>> s'
ans =
    0.0017
   -0.0065
   -0.0192
   -0.0010
    0.0005
>> news
news =
    0.0017
   -0.0065
   -0.0192
   -0.0010
    0.0005
```